# How do you make virtualenv use a version of python it did not install?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

How do you make virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper use a version of python it did not install?

Comment: You need to make a different virtualenv for that python version

Comment: I'm using virtualenvwrapper in Windows, it's different.